# How to resolve request parameters returning null when email is sent

Tags: html, angular, spring, parameters, jhipster

I am using jhipster, which uses Angular and spring boot

I have been working on this contact form that requests the user to input their information and send it. The email is sent without problems but when the email comes to the inbox the subject, name, and body text all say "null". I have tried many different options like postmapping and method.post, but it still returns the same null value.

Please help, this is the only item not working in my project

Here is my SmtpMailSender

```
@Component
  public class SmtpMailSender {
  private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
  @Autowired
  public SmtpMailSender(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
      this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;

  }

  public void sendNotification(UserModel usermodel) throws MailException{

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append("Name: " + 
      usermodel.getName()).append(System.lineSeparator());
      sb.append("\n Message: " + usermodel.getMessage());

      SimpleMailMessage mail = new SimpleMailMessage();

      mail.setTo(usermodel.getEmail());
      mail.setFrom("emailremoved@gmail.com");
      mail.setSubject(usermodel.getSubject());
      mail.setText(sb.toString());

      javaMailSender.send(mail);
      }   

      }
```

and my rootcontroller that will send the code

```
@RestController
public class RootController {

@Autowired
private SmtpMailSender smtpMailSender;

@RequestMapping("/api/contact")
public String signupSuccess(@RequestParam(value="subject",required=false) 
String subject, @RequestParam(value="message",required=false) String 
message, @RequestParam(value="email",required=false) String email, 
@RequestParam(value="name",required=false) String name) {

   UserModel usermodel = new UserModel();
   usermodel.setSubject(subject);
   usermodel.setMessage(message);
   usermodel.setEmail("emailremoved@gmail.com");

   usermodel.setName(name);
   try {
       smtpMailSender.sendNotification(usermodel);

   }catch(MailException e) {
   }


   return "redirect:/home.component.html";
    }

    }
```

And my typescriptcode

```
@Component({
selector: 'jhi-contact',
templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
styles: ['input.ng-invalid{border-left:5px solid red;}input.ng-valid{border- 
left: 5px solid green;}'],
providers: [NgbModalConfig, NgbModal]
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
model: UserModel = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    subject: '',
    message: ''
};
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, config: 
NgbModalConfig, private modalService: NgbModal) {
    config.backdrop = 'static';
    config.keyboard = false;
}
open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content);
}
ngOnInit() {}
sendNotification(): void {
    const url = 'http://localhost:9000/api/contact';
    this.http.post(url, this.model).subscribe(res => {
        location.reload();
    });
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }
   }
export interface UserModel {
name: string;
email: string;
subject: string;
message: string;
}
```